# Mapping a score to a string

Tags: javascript

```
function score_to_grade(score1) {

  var score = 100 - score1;

  if (score == 100)
    return 'A+';
  else if (score > 93)
    return 'A';
  else if (score > 87)
    return 'A-';
  else if (score > 81)
    return 'B+';
  else if (score > 69 )
    return 'B';
  else if (score > 63 )
    return 'B-';
  else if (score > 56 )
    return 'C+';
  else if (score > 44 )
    return 'C';
  else if (score > 38 )
    return 'C-';
  else if (score > 32 )
    return 'D+';
  else if (score > 19 )
    return 'D';
  else if (score == 0 )
    return 'F';
  else
    return 'D-';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function score_to_grade(pointsLost) {

  // A more meaningful name to what's subtracted from the total
  var score = 100 - pointsLost

  // A map of grade to score in "at least" basis. Examples, an A is at least 93.
  // You can easily add and remove mappings here
  var map = [
    ['A+', 100],
    ['A', 93],
    ['A-', 87],
    ['B+', 81],
    ['B', 69],
    ['B-', 63],
    ['C+', 56],
    ['C', 44],
    ['C-', 38],
    ['D+', 32],
    ['D', 19],
    ['D-', 1],
    ['F', 0]
  ]

  // Loop through the map and check if the score is at least a certain level
  for (var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
    if (score >= map[i][1]) return map[0];
  }
}
```

Comment: That assumes iterating over the properties of an object is in definition order... which you shouldn't...

Answer (score 4):

A [switch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) would serve you much better in this case.

I'm not quite sure what the line `var score = 100 - score1;` does.  is `score1` the number of points the test-taker lost?  It could use a much better name, such as `pointsLost`.

Comment: Perhaps it is just some kind of conversion. In GER we have some strange dual grading schemes: 1) [1,2,3,4,5,6] which is equivalent to US [A,B,C,D,E,F] but on the other hand a scoring system [15/14/13, 12/11/10, 9/8/7, 6/5/4, 3/2/1, 0] where you would have to write a conversion from the lower to the higher. Perhaps in this case there is a similar case. We never know ;)